# How do I say "If the download failed ... " correctly?

Tags: grammaticality

> If the download failed ...

Since `download` is a verb, it is supposed to be `downloading`. But it seems there is no one use `downloading`.

Comment: "download" is also a noun that means "the act or process of downloading data". It's perfectly fine to use "if the download failed ..."  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/download

Comment: @RubioRic Can you pls avoid answering questions in comments - it is against the site rules as it bypasses quality control.

Comment: @Astralbee Sorry, I don't agree with you, I think that if you consider my comment as an answer then this question should be closed as off-topic [basic meaning].  And I'm not sure whether the use of "downloading" is grammatically wrong or not. So I've decided just to comment. Feel free to remove my comment if you consider that it's against The Rules.

Comment: @RubioRic Maybe it should be closed but you definitely answered the question.

Comment: @Astralbee Commenting is not against the rules. Nor would I consider the comment made an actual answer. It's not an answer. Or at least not one that's fleshed out enough to be given as an answer. Had that comment been written as an answer, I would have downvoted it because it would not have been of good quality. Not providing it as an answer helped the site rather than hurt it.

Comment: *I am downloading the file now* is an example of using *downloading*. So would be *If what I'm downloading now fails . . .* So, it is used in some sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download is a verb, but it is also a *noun*.

Check [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/download):

> *a free download*

This means [it is possible to say](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2018/09/18/how-to-safely-try-linux-on-your-mac-or-windows-pc/#7f4d7d677b17):

> *If the download starts* automatically, chances are you'll find it in your Downloads folder...

A little change though; I'd use a base verb as it is 'if' structure.

> If (the) download *fails...*

Comment: As I've said to Astralbee, I wasn't sure if the use of "downloading" is completely wrong in all cases. Is it correct if you say "My downloading just failed" for example? I know that it's not exactly the same context.

Comment: It may then serve as a [gerund](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund) @rubioric.

Comment: I know and I think that it's part of the question: "no one use downloading". Why not?